# Flutter : My setState doesn't work on my boolean

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I want to switch between two image when I click on them with a boolean that I called showIOSQrcode, here is the code :

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      showIOSQrcode = !showIOSQrcode;
    });
    print(showIOSQrcode);
  },
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage(showIOSQrcode
        ? 'assets/images/qrcode_ios.png'
        : 'assets/images/qr_code_play_store.png'),
    width: 180,
  )),
```

I initialized my boolean at true like this in the build method :

```
bool showIOSQrcode = true;
```

And my image doesn't change. Also, it always print "false" onlick.

Comment: Where did you define showIOSQrcode varibale? You'd better share that code related to definition of showIOSQrcode variable. It seems that showIOSQrcode is always re-initialized whenever rebuild widget by setState.

Comment: Put bool showIOSQrcode = true; outside your build method. Because when you call SetState(), build method restart and your showIOSQrcode variable again set to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because while you call`setState` build method will call and set it true again.

Place`bool showIOSQrcode = true;`  before build method, inside state class.

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
 
  bool showIOSQrcode = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was the solution ! <3